# lotus notes creating new view but getting all documents of the database

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I am new in lotus notes.

In an existing application i want to create a new view. So i created the new view and put it in the main `-Views` folder. i copied from blank. The formula selection is `SELECT @all`. Then in the design of the view i placed 2 columns with 2 fields(`updateDate` and `updateText`) these are from a new form that i made. But now if i save and preview my View it takes a long time to index and when done i see 0 documents but i can click on every row. And if i click on a random row then it will open a random document which is in the database.. as if the view populates the whole database. And i don't get the form document where i got the fields `updateDate` and `updateText`..

How come?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the view selection formula `SELECT @all`, the view selects alle documents from the database.

So you need to change the view selection formula to for instance select documents based on the form used to create them:

```
SELECT Form="MyNewForm"
```